# How to find usages of a variable/function etc in Python?

Tags: python

So going to the declaration is great. However I want frequently to go the other way. There used to be a way to do this with one of the older ada-modes, but I've not seen anything in the python support that does this.

Is this possible in emacs and if so is there a package for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the `elpy` package built in and amazing. [elpy docs](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html) are brilliant.

As an aside, it binds to `M-?`